# What types of attacks do IdentityServer client secrets protect against?

Tags: client-server, identityserver4, identityserver3

I am trying to understand the purpose(s) of client secrets. Is it to prevent someone from creating a fake server that pretends to be my server? If not, what is it? And does it protect against anything else?

Answer (score 1):

The client secret is used to identify the application that requires an access token in order to access a resource on behalf of the user. Only clients registered in the authentication service can request access. Not only will user authentication be necessary, the client application must also be legitimate. Otherwise someone could impersonate the client application.

This type of client authorization should only be used by confidential clients ([OAuth2 Client Types][2]).

> confidential

- ```
   Clients capable of maintaining the confidentiality of their
  credentials (e.g., client implemented on a secure server with
  restricted access to the client credentials), or capable of secure
  client authentication using other means.
  ```

> public

- ```
   Clients incapable of maintaining the confidentiality of their
  credentials (e.g., clients executing on the device used by the
  resource owner, such as an installed native application or a web
  browser-based application), and incapable of secure client
  authentication via any other means.
  ```

When using flows with clients that cannot guarantee the confidentiality of this secret (i.e. implicit), the identity of the client cannot be verified. In those cases it can be verified by means of the redirection URI. As an additional measure, it should limit the exposure of refresh tokens.

Officially it is no longer recommended to use the implicit flow for security reasons, the recommendation for this type of clients is **Authorization Code + PKCE** extension. [See OBBA document][1]

> For authorizing users within a browser-based application, the best current practice is to
>
> o  Use the OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow with the PKCE
> extension
>
> o  Require the OAuth 2.0 state parameter

> o  Recommend exact matching of redirect URIs, and require the
> hostname of the redirect URI match the hostname of the URL the app
> was served from
>
> o  Do not return access tokens in the front channel

[1]: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-parecki-oauth-browser-based-apps-02)
[2]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have some ApiResources which called by Clients and there is no any user in the flow. for example fetch instagram's post using instagram's api. now instagram wants to control client behavior so client should be authorized for instagram befor any api call. in this situation you need define some secret for each client to identify them.
This an example of client's secret usage.